# Suggestions to improve sem results

Tags: model, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I wish to check the assumption that physical and mental health for elders are affected by two main latent factors the physical burden (PHB) and the emotional burden (EMB). The measurement model is as follows:
[image: measurement model]

AGE: Individual's age

CAR: Cardiac disorder

HYP: Hypertension

DIA: Diabetes

OTH: Other physical illness

OAS: Shame (Inner)

ESS: Shame (Outer)

CAQ: Cardiac anxiety

PHI: Physical health index (SF-36)

MHI: Mental health index (SF-36)

The results of the code

```
HEART.model <- '
# measurement model 
# Physical burden factor is reflected on objective measures. Age: scale, Cardiac disorder, hypertension, diabetes, otherpd: binomal (0,1)
PHBURDEN =~ AGE + CARDIACDISORDER + HYPERTASIS + DIABETES + OTHERPHYSICALDISEASE

# Emotional burden factor is reflected on pessimism and shame (inner and outer)
EMBURDEN =~ OASTOTAL + ESSTOTAL + CAQTOTAL

# Physical health index (SF-36) is regressed on Objective and Subjective factors.
PHI2 ~ PHBURDEN + EMBURDEN

# Mental health index (SF-36) is regressed on Objective and Subjective factors.
MHI2 ~ PHBURDEN + EMBURDEN

# residual correlations
# the unexplained variance from two variables are correlated
# you can hypothesise the existence of a latent (unmeasured) variable
PHBURDEN ~~ EMBURDEN
PHBURDEN ~~ 1 * PHBURDEN
EMBURDEN ~~ 1 * EMBURDEN

#AGE ~~ 1 * AGE
OASTOTAL ~~ 1 * OASTOTAL
ESSTOTAL ~~ 1 * ESSTOTAL
CAQTOTAL ~~ 1 * CAQTOTAL
'

fit <- lavaan:::cfa(HEART.model, data = mydata, std.lv=TRUE, estimator = "MLM")
summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
```

is:

```
> fit <- lavaan:::cfa(HEART.model, data = mydata, std.lv=TRUE, estimator = "MLM")
Warning message:
In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label,  :
lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 1000 times  larger than others; use varTable(fit) to investigate
> summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
lavaan (0.5-20) converged normally after  71 iterations

                                              Used       Total
  Number of observations                           177         178

  Estimator                                         ML      Robust
  Minimum Function Test Statistic             9297.448      64.374
  Degrees of freedom                                34          34
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.001
  Scaling correction factor                                144.428
    for the Satorra-Bentler correction

Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic              499.052     494.253
  Degrees of freedom                                45          45
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000

User model versus baseline model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.000       0.932
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                     -26.002       0.911

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)              -7632.485   -7632.485
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)      -2983.761   -2983.761

  Number of free parameters                         31          31
  Akaike (AIC)                               15326.970   15326.970
  Bayesian (BIC)                             15425.431   15425.431
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)        15327.260   15327.260

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          1.241       0.071
  90 Percent Confidence Interval          1.220  1.262       0.069  0.073
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000       0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.149       0.149

Parameter Estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Standard Errors                           Robust.sem

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  Z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  PHBURDEN =~                                                           
    AGE              -2.456    0.758   -3.238    0.001   -2.456   -0.337
    CARDIACDISORDE   -0.189    0.044   -4.344    0.000   -0.189   -0.395
    HYPERTASIS       -0.072    0.044   -1.659    0.097   -0.072   -0.145
    DIABETES         -0.080    0.034   -2.392    0.017   -0.080   -0.231
    OTHERPHYSICALD   -0.040    0.031   -1.277    0.202   -0.040   -0.109
  EMBURDEN =~                                                           
    OASTOTAL          7.281    0.647   11.252    0.000    7.281    0.991
    ESSTOTAL         12.939    0.885   14.613    0.000   12.939    0.997
    CAQTOTAL          0.382    0.055    6.981    0.000    0.382    0.357

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  Z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  PHI2 ~                                                                
    PHBURDEN          1.519    0.399    3.808    0.000    1.519    0.827
    EMBURDEN          0.037    0.331    0.112    0.911    0.037    0.020
  MHI2 ~                                                                
    PHBURDEN          0.679    0.249    2.727    0.006    0.679    0.514
    EMBURDEN         -0.263    0.181   -1.454    0.146   -0.263   -0.199

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  Z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  PHBURDEN ~~                                                           
    EMBURDEN         -0.446    0.139   -3.196    0.001   -0.446   -0.446
  PHI2 ~~                                                               
    MHI2              0.725    0.417    1.741    0.082    0.725    0.668

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  Z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    AGE              74.192    0.549  135.053    0.000   74.192   10.180
    CARDIACDISORDE    0.356    0.036    9.862    0.000    0.356    0.743
    HYPERTASIS        0.531    0.038   14.118    0.000    0.531    1.064
    DIABETES          0.141    0.026    5.380    0.000    0.141    0.406
    OTHERPHYSICALD    0.158    0.028    5.751    0.000    0.158    0.433
    OASTOTAL         17.169    0.740   23.217    0.000   17.169    2.336
    ESSTOTAL         45.424    1.016   44.694    0.000   45.424    3.500
    CAQTOTAL          1.575    0.063   25.164    0.000    1.575    1.472
    PHI2              4.849    0.138   35.024    0.000    4.849    2.640
    MHI2              5.023    0.100   50.425    0.000    5.023    3.801
    PHBURDEN          0.000                               0.000    0.000
    EMBURDEN          0.000                               0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  Z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    PHBURDEN          1.000                               1.000    1.000
    EMBURDEN          1.000                               1.000    1.000
    OASTOTAL          1.000                               1.000    0.019
    ESSTOTAL          1.000                               1.000    0.006
    CAQTOTAL          1.000                               1.000    0.873
    AGE              47.085    5.408    8.707    0.000   47.085    0.886
    CARDIACDISORDE    0.193    0.018   10.665    0.000    0.193    0.844
    HYPERTASIS        0.244    0.007   36.664    0.000    0.244    0.979
    DIABETES          0.115    0.018    6.484    0.000    0.115    0.947
    OTHERPHYSICALD    0.132    0.019    7.110    0.000    0.132    0.988
    PHI2              1.114    0.797    1.399    0.162    1.114    0.330
    MHI2              1.057    0.245    4.312    0.000    1.057    0.606
```

For the above results it seems that the model is not the appropriate way to interpret the data.

Is this correct or I could make any modification in order to improve the outcome?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram is not a measurement model, since it appears that you are regressing the latent variables on two observed variables, `PHI` and `MHI`. This kind of recursive model looks like it might not be identified. However I don't see these regressions in the code, so I wonder if you have posted the correct diagram for the code ? The way I read your code, PHI and MHI are additional indicators for *both* latent variables.

I would have thought that there should be residual covariances between the indicators for each latent variable. For example, there should surely be covariance between age, cardiac disorder, hypertension and diabetes not explained by your model, and possibly between these and cardiac anxiety - as well as others (theory and clinical expertise should drive these modifications, although you could use modification indices to help).  This should improve the model fit.

Why are you fitting intercepts ? This isn't necessary in a measurement model, though it shouldn't affect model fit. Note that you can use `meanstructure = TRUE` in the fitting function to do this more conveniently.

Have you checked for normality of the observed variables (since you are using the MLR estimator) ?

Also, you could try standardising your data since the variance of `AGE` is very much larger than the variance of the others (though I doubt this will help model fit)

**Edit:**

Further to your comment, I would suggest adding `CARDIACDISORDER~~HYPERTASIS`, `CARDIACDISORDER~~DIABETES`, `HYPERTASIS~~DIABETES` as well as `AGE`and `CAQTOTAL` with those 3 variables.

Also, note that regressing an observed variable on a latent variable is equivalent to adding that variable as an indicator of the latent variable.  To see this you can run the following models with the built-in dataset HolzingerSwineford1939

```
# model with regressions of 2 observed variables on 2 latent variables

HS.model1 <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3 
               speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9   
               x4 ~ visual + speed
               x5 ~ visual + speed
'

# model with the same 2 observed variables as indicators
HS.model2 <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
               speed   =~ x4 + x5 + x7 + x8 + x9
               x4 ~~ x5
'

fit1 <- cfa(HS.model1, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, std.lv=TRUE, meanstructure=TRUE)

summary(fit1, fit.measures = TRUE)

fit2 <- cfa(HS.model2, data = HolzingerSwineford1939, std.lv=TRUE, meanstructure=TRUE)

summary(fit2, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

Note how the model fit statistics, and all the parameter estimates and standard errors are identical. The only difference is that in `HS.model2` the regressions are now factor loadings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your effort. 1). The relations I wish to test are PHI2 ~ PHBURDEN + EMBURDEN and MHI2 ~ PHBURDEN + EMBURDEN thus I regress the two latent on the two observed. 2). Mardia's Multivariate Normality Test rejected multivariate normality and that is the reason that I applied MLR estimator. 3). I added residual covariances in the model (e.g. ESSTOTAL ~~ OASTOTAL) with no luck. 4). meanstructure = TRUE did not produce any difference. 5). I already standardised PHI and MHI in order to decrease the differences in variance but with no luck.

Comment: Sorry for not appropriate use of "measurement model" and thanks for the helpful update in your answer. I also tried the suggested residual covariances but with no luck. Further, I tried the model up to the definition of the latent variable but with no satisfactory results. I end to admit that the data are not appropriate for such an analysis. Thank you for your help.